# create a column of sequential numbers

Tags: calculated-column

I want to create a column that auto numbers items as they are added to the list. In my instance, I want to count how many people who RSVP for an event.

Comment: Do you want total number of items in the list?

Comment: The built in ID field already auto numbers new items. Have you considered using that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without (re)creating an existing auto incrementing field, ID.

Simply create a view in your list that is grouped by event and add a Count in the Totals section of the view configuration. This will group all the respondents together based on the event and give you a total of responses.